# Serait-il correct de comprendre la répétition dans rejaillit/rage comme une homéotéleute ?

Tags: figure-de-style, son

Bonjour,

J'ai trouvé ce passage dans *Guignol's Band I* :

> Il r**eja**illit du ciel en fronde égrenant sa r**age**!...

Y a-t-il un nom pour la répétition phonique dans *rejaillit*/*rage* ? Je ne pense pas à l'allitération des *r*. Serait-il correct de la comprendre comme une homéotéleute ?

Comment: À la personne qui m'a donné un downvote : pourriez-vous m'en donner une raison, s'il vous plaît ?

Comment: Bonjour, Ovide. Contente de vous revoir. :)

Comment: @Oreste Merci beaucoup, c'est très gentil ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit d'une allitération également : les allitérations concernent les répétitions de consonnes, et le son [j] est une consonne palatale. Si le son répété était une voyelle, il s'agirait alors d'une *assonance*. Le mot rage étant le seul à se terminer en [aj], il est difficile de considérer que la phrase soit une homéotéleute.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse.